# Homology group for critical points

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, regularity-theory-of-pdes

What is the connection between critical points of a functional over an infinite dimensional Banach space and a critical group at that point?. For instance, I was wondering as to what is the significance of computing the critical group $C^q(I,u)=H^q(I^c\cap U,I^c\cap U\setminus\{u\})$, $q\geq 0$?. Here $I$ is the $C^1$ functional over the Banach space $X$, $I^c=\{v:I(v)\leq c\}$, $U$ is a neighbourhood of the critical point $u\in X$.

Comment: You asked this exact question at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3478795/497007 and it was closed because it needed more details/clarity. You should consider doing so instead of just reposting your same question word-for-word.

Comment: @ Glitch Is that the right link?. You are directing me to my own previous question. I have already clarified it there and again have clarified my question here in this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The clarity was already provided. The link you provided has the clearer version of the question. The older question didn't have the mathematical detail in it. The older version just had "What is the connection between critical points of a functional over an infinite dimensional Banach space and a critical group at that point?."